# Trying to change Tumblr CSS but

Tags: css

I am trying to edit the main-min.css in tumblr and when I put this into the browser

http://static.tumblr.com/vr9xgox/K7fnmibsu/main-min.css

I get a bunch of scrambled mess. It wasn't like this before. Before it was all organized and whatever I wanted to change I just find by the line number.

Am I doing something wrong?

Example:

```
    /*! normalize.css v1.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,

canvas,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-size:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}button,html,input,select,textarea{font-family:sans-serif}a:focus{outline:dotted thin}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}h2{font-size:1.5em;margin:.83em 0}h3{font-size:1.17em;margin:1em 0}h4

{font-size:1em;margin:1.33em 0}h5{font-size:.83em;margin:1.67em 0}h6{font-size:.67em;margin:2.33em 0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}blockquote{margin:1em 40px}dfn{font-style:italic}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}p,pre{margin:1em 0}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}q{quotes:none}q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}dl,menu,ol,ul{margin:1em 0}dd{margin:0 0 0 40px}menu,ol,ul{padding:0 0 0 40px}nav ol,nav ul{list-style:none}img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure,form{margin:0}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0;white-space:normal}button,input,select,textarea{font-size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline}button,input{line-height:normal}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:

pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}@font-face{font-family:optica-icons;src:url(http://static.tumblr.com/vr9xgox/Laznfengw/optica-icons.eot)}@font-face{font-family:optica-icons;src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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

BMBYzMiQxFTcnFSEiBgcOARURNzU0Njc+ATMBITUHFzUhMjY3PgE1EQcVFAYHDgEjAQBHHlwBFNbW/ccKGAsLD4EGBgUQCQIN/h7W1gJTCg8GBgZ+BgQFCgUCVwMDgsK+ggcHBhEK/uJ5RQQHAwID/qiBwb+DBQUEDgoBKn9ABQgCAwMAAQDVAIADMwKrACQAAAEyFhceARcWBgcOAQcuAScuATc+ATc+ATMeARceARc+ATc+ATcClBk3GBcfAQErKClwQ0RwKSgsAQEgFxg3GRktExMcBwgcExMtGQKrEhUWRzQ7Zy0uUSUlUS4tZzs0RxYVEgEZEBEhCQkhEBEZAQAAAAADAIABVQOAAgAAGQAzAE0AAAEiBgcOARUUFhceATMyNjc
```

Comment: min mean minified, this file is like this on purpose.

Comment: I did this before to change the css and it was organized, but now it seems to be like this. Does tumblr not want us to change the css anymore?

Comment: I don't use tumblr so I can't tell you. Is there a main.css ? Can't you add another personal stylesheet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Write your own block of css after the above code is called. So if your template has: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.tumblr.com/vr9xgox/K7fnmibsu/main-min.css">`

Below that create a new style tag, and inside you can write the css rules you wish to overide here is an example:

```
<style>
#menu {
background:#F00;
}
</style>
```

If the file called previously contains #menu {background:#000;} your css will now take precedence as it is read afterwards.

You can inspect the code in the browser to see what rules are applied to different elements.

2. You could download the linked css file. Delete it's reference from your css template, and then edit that file yourself, and then link it back to the template if you upload it as a new resource. If you do this you can also run the code through a beautifier, like this: http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

I think the first option is better and makes sense in terms of the hierarchy.

Comment: Both are great options thank you so much!

Comment: @user3173447 can you vote on this, if it helped you out? :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mehdi Brillaud points out in his comment: `min` in a filename shows a script or style to be minified. This is done to save space and make resources load quicker by removing all whitespace.

If the style wasn't like this before, then perhaps you've changed something to set the site in 'production'. A quick search pointed me [here](http://liferaytips.tumblr.com/post/11401820924/debug-with-un-minified-css-or-javascript-code-in), which might help you.

In short, add `?css_fast_load=0` at the end of the URL, and the CSS should no longer be minified.